# Anguilla | FilteredListControl load Event

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme, gui-extensions

Hi GUI/Anguilla Experts,

I am trying to call a function once FilteredListControl (shows items in the right panel in tridion GUI) finished loading. I am adding event handler as below but it doesn't work. I've tried "start" and "draw" events as well but no luck.

```
var FilteredListControl = $display.getView().getFilteredListControl();
$evt.addEventHandler(FilteredListControl, "load", function(){alert('loaded')});
```

Any idea what's wrong with this?

**Update**

The problem I am trying to solve is, when a user selects a repository item in left panel and right panel gets refreshed, at that event I want to place a search textbox just above the results, same as this [plugin](http://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/Publication-Panel-Search).

Comment: Are you "waiting" for the $display object to be ready? can you put here what errors you get in the console if any?

Comment: Hi Jaime, yeah I am waiting for the $display object to be ready. The code in the question is the part of "onDashboardLoaded" function I am calling in `$evt.addEventHandler($display, "start", onDashboardLoaded)`. Also I am getting the FilteredListControl object, loging it in the console.

Comment: does such object (FilteredListControl) trigger a "load" event? What are you trying to accomplish, by the way.

Comment: I am not sure about the events associated with "FilteredListControl", is there a way to find those events, any documentation? Also I've updated my question mentioning the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Using Albert's code as below I figured out that `FilteredListControl` didn't has any event associated with it.

```
$evt.addEventHandler(FilteredListControl, "*", function(event){console.log(event);});
```

Then I extracted the `list` control from it and that does have the "draw" event associated with it. Attaching a event handler function to this event solve my problem.

Code:

```
var filteredListControl = $display.getView().getFilteredListControl();

var listControl = filteredListControl.getList();

$evt.addEventHandler(listControl, "draw", myHandlerFunction);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `FilteredListControl` doesn't fire one of those events. You can check which events are fired by attaching a listener to all events. E.g.:

```
$evt.addEventHandler(FilteredListControl, "*", function(event){console.log(event);});
```

To achieve what you want you have to attach an event handler to the TreeViewControl like this:

```
var treeControl = $display.getView().getTreeControl()
$evt.addEventHandler(treeControl, "select", function(event){console.log('selected');});
```

I'm not entirely sure if this event fires at the correct moment, but for placing a textbox it should suffice